# get collection data based on id fetched in listing in nested lookups and conditional lookup in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, nested-loops, lookup, aggregation

I just need following output

```
{
message: "Details are:",
status: 1,
data:[
    {
    leadId: "92106",
    projectName: "Sales Rep Mobile App with Shopify Backend"
    projectOverview: "<any description>"
    notificationsData:[
        {
           _id:"6076e2593580d805814c338e",
           content:"<strong>User Jangid</strong> posted a comment about this message on estimation portal.",
           estimationId:"5f75a496c70f05559088d971",
           commentId:"6076e2583580d805814c338b",
           commentData:{
              _id:"6076e2583580d805814c338b",
              content:"<p>hello krishna this is and this is second&nbsp;</p>\n"
           }
        },
        {
           _id:"6077c7c75c1bfc051f8dff3e",
           content:"<strong>User Nunna</strong> posted a comment about this message on estimation portal.",
           estimationId:"5f75a496c70f05559088d971",
           commentId:"6077c7c35c1bfc051f8dff3b",
           commentData:{
              _id:"6077c7c35c1bfc051f8dff3b",
              content:"<p>hey hiiii</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n"
           }
        },    
     ],
     userName:"user Nunna",
     profileImage:"profile url",
     isViewed:true,
     isSortByStatus:2,
     isNotifyEst:1
  } 
]
```

}

In the above example i have multiple list of same type of collection
and this list is i aggregate with **`Estimation Collection`**

These Above Data if fetched based on **`Estimation Collection`**

so based on this **`Estimation Collection's`**  **`_id`** i need to fetch notification and based on `commentId` that fetched inside **`notification collection`** i need to fetch **`comments collection`** data.

i already do aggregation with some more collection i only need the **`notification`** and **`comment`** data inside **`notificationData`** array

Answer (score 0):

Yes i Achieve this i use following query for that

```
let estData = await Estimations.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "notifications", as: "notificationsData",
        let: {
            estimation_id: "$_id"
        },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $and: [
                            { $eq: ['$estimationId', "$$estimation_id"] },
                            { $eq: ['$userId', ObjectId(this.req.currentUser._id)] },
                            { $eq: ['$isViewed', false] },
                        ]
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                $lookup:
                {
                    from: "comments",
                    localField: "commentId",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "commentData"
                }
            },
            { "$unwind": "$commentData" },

        ],
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        projectName: 1,
        "notificationsData.content": 1,
        "notificationsData.estimationId": 1,
        "notificationsData._id": 1,
        "notificationsData.commentId": 1,
        "notificationsData.commentData.content": 1,
        "notificationsData.commentData._id": 1,
        leadId: 1,
        projectOverview: 1
    }
},
```

])

in the above query i get **`notificationData`** based on **`estimationId`** and **`commentData`** data based on **`commentId`** that is specified inside **`notificationData`**

so here it is solution that i do and works fine.